# Why CAN-FD trailer is different?

Tags: microcontroller, can

I created my own board based on the ATSAME70 Xplained, in order to control a sensor via CAN-FD and receive the data via USB.

I am running the same firmware in both boards, but in my version, the trailer
Of frame is different.

Can the hardware be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the non-ISO CAN-FD (also called Bosch CAN-FD)?

https://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/can/can-fd/

The only differences are a few extra bits in the CRC. Can you check the frame CRC-length?

Most new products support ISO CAN-FD, but your microcontroller seams to support both:
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemtest/MCU32/ProductDocuments/Brochures/60001427C.pdf

Comment: Seams to be my problem. Apparently the Rev.A of the Microcontroller I am using only supports non ISO CAN-FD. Is there any work around?

Comment: Non-ISO and ISO CAN-FD devices can't share the same bus, so except that the other device can be used with CAN 2.0 you may have no alternative than using a different microcontroller.